# Get histogram of number of vertices per component of graph H

Tags: graphs-and-networks, histograms

I have a huge graph with ~8k vertices and ~1k components. I want a histogram showing the number of vertices for each component. How do I do this?

EDIT: I'm trying ubpdqn's approach, but not gettting the expected results. Here are the details of my graph and the resulting histogram:

```
H = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "HighEnergyTheoryCollaborations"}]

Histogram[Length /@ ConnectedComponents[H], LabelingFunction -> Above, BaseStyle -> 20]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm using google but cannot find functions that do what I want. I do ConnectedComponents[G] and I get the labels of all vertices, grouped in components. I do Length@ConnectedComponents[G] and I get the number of components. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it the underlying problem is in the OP'sdata and not in _Mathematica_.

Comment: @Öskå " If you remove it" remove what exactly?

Comment: You could use `Histogram[Log /@ Length /@ ConnectedComponents[H], LabelingFunction -> Above]`

Comment: Your result looks perfectly correct to me.  It says simply that most of the connected components are quite small.  You should probably accept the answer given by @ubpdqn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a toy example:

Generate toy graph

```
g = Graph[
   UndirectedEdge @@@ 
    RandomSample[Subsets[Union[RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, 1000]], {2}], 
     200]];
```

Mine:
[image]

Histogram can be obtained by mapping `Length` to `ConnectedComponents`:

```
Histogram[Length /@ ConnectedComponents[g], LabelingFunction -> Above,
  BaseStyle -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this approach but getting strange result. I added to my question.